# Is there any chance to reduce PyTorch lib_pytorch_jni.so file size

Tags: android, pytorch, torchvision, image-classification

I am looking into PyTorch official mobile example apps on Github specifically PyTorchDempApp for on device image classification. https://github.com/pytorch/android-demo-app/tree/master/PyTorchDemoApp.
I noticed that lib_pytorch_jni.so file size is ~10M [lib_pytorch_jni](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AugXX.png). Is there any chance to reduce that size.
Also, I am planning to use a custom module to fit my needs, does that mean that I will be getting the same size mentioned above.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The code is in the link I posted. I have attached a screenshot for the library size I am talking about. Thanks